# Decimal expansion of real numbers and countability

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let S be the set of all real numbers in the interval (0,1) whose decimal expansions involve only 0 and 1. Prove that S is uncountable.

assume that S is countable. then elements a1, a2, a3, a4 belong to S.
a1 = 0.a11a12a13a14...
a2= 0.a21a22a2324...
a3= 0.a31a32a33a34...
a4 = 0.a41a42a43a44...

ai is either 0 or 1. then b1,b2,b3,b4... bi = 0, if aii= 1, and bi = 1, if aii= 0...

this is all I have

Comment: Have you seen the standard diagonal argument? Can you apply it to a collection of binary sequences?

Comment: This should be easier than the standard diagonalization of the reals, since there are no numbers that can be represented twice in this format.

Comment: I dont get the standard diagonal argument and am confused

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to do this. Do the standard diagonalization proof is one. (see eg my book Proof Patterns).

Another is to interpret each decimal expansion as a binary expansion and observe that you get a bijection with (0,1] which is uncountable.